# How can I get the value of cells in the same column while reading from Access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table in my database and I need to get the value of cells corresponding to the same column and display them in three different textboxes. The code I got is:

```
    if (numberOrResults == 1)
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmdDataBase = conDataBase.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        // We declare the text of the query
                        cmdDataBase.CommandText =
                            "SELECT User_Subject.* FROM User_Subject WHERE User_ID = @user_id";

                        cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
                        {
                            new OleDbParameter("@user_id", currentUser.ID)
                        });

                        // Open database if not open
                        if (conDataBase.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                            conDataBase.Open();

                        // We need to use a using statement since OleDbDataReader inherits DbDataReader which implements IDisposable
                        // more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx
                        using (OleDbDataReader myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            var ordinals = new
                            {
                                Sub_Id = myReader.GetOrdinal("Subject_ID"),
                                Score = myReader.GetOrdinal("Score"),
                            };

                            while (myReader != null && myReader.Read())
                            {
                                // We read the data from the selected columns, rows and cells
                                currentUser.addSubject(myReader.GetInt32(ordinals.Sub_Id), myReader.GetInt32(ordinals.Score));
                                currentUser.English = myReader[4].ToString();
                                currentUser.Maths = myReader[5].ToString();
                                currentUser.Physics = myReader[6].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The table got three columns and I would like to get the values of the cells in the third column. Now the displayed data in the textboxes are three cells in the same row.

Comment: Can you provide your table schema and query and intended results? Also, you shouldn't have to check if myReader is null if you just created it.

Comment: how can I post the schema of the table? My intended result is to get the values in the first, the second, the third row only for last column.

Comment: If you only want one column to display then only include one column in your query.  If you want three rows then call Read on your data reader three times.  Don't use a loop at all, unless maybe a 'for' loop that iterates three times.

Comment: I actually think that I made mistakes building the database. What my application should do is: at the Login check if the user is a teacher or student and open the correspondent form. I got stuck because I cannot load properly the data I need and cannot finish to implement some command. If anybody is willing to help me, I will say a big THANK YOU. I have started to code just a few months ago and I am not very skilled at the moment but I would really like to understand what I am doing. Cheers.